# Node.js + Sequelize + SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, datetimeoffset

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and node.js with

```
"dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0",
    "tedious": "^5.0.3"
  }
```

And I'm trying to create this database

```js
const con = require('./../dbo/connect');
const Processo = con.db.define('processo', {
    Id: {
        type: con.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    Cavalo: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    Reboque: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    CNPJTransportadora: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    Motorista: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    CNH: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    EntradaCarreta: { type: con.Sequelize.DATE },
    SaidaCarreta: { type: con.Sequelize.DATE },
    Tara: { type: con.Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 3)  },
    PesoBruto: { type: con.Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 3)  },
    Conteiner: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    Dimensao: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    IsoCode: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    GMCI: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    DT: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    Navio: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    Viagem: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    Origem: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    CodOrigem: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    Destino: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    CodDestino: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING },
    Regime: { type: con.Sequelize.STRING }
});
Processo.sync();
module.exports = {
    Processo,
    Sequelize:con.Sequelize
};
```

But when run the Sync function, I get this error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Column, parameter, or
>   variable #7: Cannot find data type DATETIMEOFFSET.
>       at Query.formatError (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modules\s
>   equelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:315:12)
>       at Request.connection.lib.Request [as userCallback] (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\r
>   ecepcao-processo\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:107:25)
>       at Request.callback (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modules\te
>   dious\lib\request.js:37:27)
>       at Connection.endOfMessageMarkerReceived (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-pro
>   cesso\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2118:20)
>       at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_mo
>   dules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1136:36)
>       at Parser.tokenStreamParser.on (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node
>   _modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:941:14)
>       at Parser.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at Parser.parser.on.token (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modu
>   les\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
>       at Parser.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at addChunk (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modules\readable-s
>   tream\lib_stream_readable.js:296:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modules\re
>   adable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:278:11)
>       at Parser.Readable.push (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_module
>   s\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:239:10)
>       at Parser.Transform.push (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modul
>   es\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js:139:32)
>       at Parser.afterTransform (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modul
>   es\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js:88:10)
>       at Parser._transform (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modules\t
>   edious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:41:7)
>       at Parser.Transform._read (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modu
>   les\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js:177:10)
>       at Parser.Transform._write (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_mod
>   ules\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js:164:83)
>       at doWrite (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modules\readable-st
>   ream\lib_stream_writable.js:405:139)
>       at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modules\reada
>   ble-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:394:5)
>       at Parser.Writable.write (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modul
>   es\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:303:11)
>       at Parser.addEndOfMessageMarker (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\nod
>   e_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:45:24)
>       at Connection.message (C:\Users\tiago.santos\Desktop\Labs\diariamente-ts\node\gmci-e\recepcao-processo\node_modules\
>   tedious\lib\connection.js:2107:32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this far away of the best solution, but i solved this way:

```js
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const paths = {
    datatypes: `${__dirname}/../../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/data-types.js`
};

async function rewriteFile(path, find, replace) {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(paths[path], 'utf-8');
    let newValue = data.replace(find, replace);
    return await fs.writeFileSync(paths[path], newValue, 'utf-8');
}
module.exports = {
    rewriteFile
}
```

And run bellow code before start express:

```js
const sequelizeBug = require('./../api/helpers/sequelize-bug');
sequelizeBug.rewriteFile('datatypes', 'DATETIMEOFFSET','DATETIME');
```

if anyone have a best solution, i accept, thks.